# How does the 737 MAX MCAS differ from stab trim in other 737 variants?

Tags: flight-controls, boeing-737

I have the following questions:

1. MCAS will not cut out from excessive control column movement as non-MAX 737 aircraft stab trim does. Is that correct, and is this cutout permanent or does it  re-engage after the control column forces/movement are relieved?
2. MCAS can adjust the stabilizer to its hard stops whereas non-MAX 737 aircraft have soft limits. Is that correct?
3. MCAS operates the trim wheel motor in approximately 10 second bursts with 5 second pauses. What do non-MAX 737 aircraft do?

Comment: You might want to break this up into separate questions lest your post get down voted for being too broad.

Comment: Normal and non-normal Stab Trim operation is the same for all B737 variants. Only the B737 Max has MCAS and therefore it’s operating characteristics really can’t be compared to the other variants.

Comment: @MikeSowsun Of course they can: both STS and MCAS adjust the same flight control surface.